# Batch script explanation

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to batch scripts and I don't know what `>nul` in this self-replicating file code means.Can you explain it please?

```
copy %0 "new.bat" > nul
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` means: "put the output to..."

`nul` is a "Nirwana-Device"

so

`> nul` will send the output of the `copy`command to Nirwana, so that it doesn't write to the screen.

You could also write the output to a file with `>file.txt`

For example try these lines:

```
echo hello world
echo hello world again >nul
echo hello beautiful world >file.txt 
type file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like what Stephan said, these examples work very well too.

```
timeout /t 01
timeout /t 01>nul
```

`timeout` is a command that is a timer which will countdown (in seconds) the specified number you type (which is `01` in this example) `/t` simply stands for time.